# Apply an Azure Policy to a management group using ARM

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

**Goal**: Deploy an Azure Policy to a management group so when certain tags are missing from a resource within its remit, apply the specified Tag from the resource group

**Problem**: Deploying this template to the management group results in "'*The template function 'RESOURCEGROUP' is not expected at this location.*"

There is a fairly plain structure similar to:

```
<Management Group> - <Subscription 1> - <Resource Group 1> - <Resource A>
                                      - <Resource Group 2> - <Resource B>
                   - <Subscription 2> - <Resource Group 3> - <Resource C>
                                                           - <Resource D>
```

There is a fairly simple template using a nested policy definition:

```
......
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "name": ".",
      "properties": {
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "displayName": ".",
        "description": ".",
        "metadata": {
          "category": "Tags"
        },
        "policyRule": {
          "if": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "tags['costCenter']",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "tags['CostCenter']",
                "notin": "[parameters('allowedCostCenter')]"
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "effect": "modify",
            "details": {
              "roleDefinitionIds": [
                "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4a9ae827-6dc8-4573-8ac7-8239d42aa03f"
              ],
              "operations": [
                {
                  "operation": "add",
                  "field": "tags['CostCenter']",
                  "value": "[resourcegroup().tags['CostCenter']]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I realise that you can not use "resourcegroup()" on items that are not within a resource group, but the guides suggested using this within the nested template and on "indexed" resources should work.

- I'm fairly sure the pipeline is correct as I already have several audit policies deploying
- From experimenting in the portal, this looks like it should be possible
- There is a decent amount of reading around, but I have not read (or at least understood) that seems to help with this

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? If so, can you see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add escape character if you want resourcegroup() function to be executed as a part of the Azure Policy, not the MG-scope ARM template:

```
"value": "[[resourcegroup().tags['CostCenter']]"
```